# CakePHP find() conditions for association entries

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, has-many

I have following command, getting me entries from my DB with associated hasMany entries:

```
$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Teaser.published' => 1
    ),
));
```

Now also the `posts` entries will be fetched, due the `hasMany` relation.

The output looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Teaser' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '63',
            'token' => '56d455bc20cfb56d455bc20d08',
            // this goes on
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'teaser_id' => '1',
                'title' => 'blabla',
                'text' => 'blabla',
                'published' => 1,
                // this goes on
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now my question is, how can I include something in the `conditions`, to filter also the `Post`-entries?

When I enter it like this, I get an error:

```
$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Teaser.published' => 1,
        'Post.published' => 1
    )
));
```

Comment: what error you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is that your relationship is a `hasMany` so when Cake does the `contain` it is actually doing more than one query for your `find`. As a result you can't specify `'Post.published' => 1` in the conditions as the `Post` alias won't exist in the primary query (the one retrieving your teasers).

Instead you need to pass the extra condition as part of the contain:-

```
$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all', [
    'contain' => [
        'Post' => [
            'conditions' => [
                'Post.published' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        'Teaser.published' => 1,
    ]
]);
```

This will let Cake know the conditions you want to use when building the query for the posts.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation for [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and [retrieving data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data). These are basics.

```
$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all', array(
    'contain' => [
        'Post' => [
            'conditions' => [
                'published' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => array(
        'Teaser.published' => 1,
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write condition in your model `Teaser.php` like

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'conditions' => array('Post.published' => 1)
    )
);
```